# C# shorthand for 2 or conditions

Tags: c#

I have the following statement in C#

```
if(user.member.RegistrationDate.Value.Month == 10 || user.member.RegistrationDate.Value.Month == 11)
```

My question is, is there a way to write this in shorthand eg;

```
if(user.member.RegistrationDate.Value.Month == 10 || 11)
```

Comment: If those are expensive getters of properties (or you just want to make it more readable) it may make sense to simply get value into temp variable: `var value = user.member.RegistrationDate.Value.Month;` and then you can `if(value == 10 || value == 11) { ... }`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
 if (new []{10,11}.Contains( user.member.RegistrationDate.Value.Month))
```