# Possible shorthand solution for OR operator issue

Tags: c#, shorthand, or-operator

I tried to come up with a shorthand solution for an **or** operator. So I came up with something like this, but the result is always false.

Can someone give some advice on how can I fix this issue? Will this even work at all? If not, are there any other solutions similar to this?

*P.S. I know that this question has been asked before, but unfortunately, none of the solutions suited my needs.*

**The code:**

```
public static bool IsEqualsTo(object o, params object[] p)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        if (o == p[i])
        { return true; }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So for example:

> **From** *if (MovementState == PMovementState.Walking || MovementState == PMovementState.Idle)*
>
> **to** *if (IsEqualsTo(MovementState, PMovementState.Walking, PMovementState.Idle))*

or

> **From** *if (input.text == "text" || input.text == "text2" || input.text == "text3")*
>
> **to** *if (IsEqualsTo(input.text, "text", "text2", "text3"))*

Comment: _I know that this question has been asked before, but unfortunately, none of the solutions suited my needs._ : Can you provide any link to the questions you referring ?

Comment: And the reason why those answers didn't suit.

Comment: This is really `Enumerable.Contains` but with a `params` array, and it would be easily implemented in terms of that.

Comment: No repro with the text example. `IsEqualsTo` returns `true` even with `object`

Comment: Also, why does the code you have here not work?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Pac0 Hey there! These are the questions I viewed when I was looking for the possible solution on the topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40465720/c-sharp-shorthand-for-2-or-conditions or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2bba32df-fa2a-4749-8505-5b8eddc4fe9c/shorthand-for-multiple-ors?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a generic version to avoid boxing/unboxing:

```
public static bool IsEqualsTo<T>(T o, params T[] p)
{
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default; // make it an optional parameter
    for (int i = 0; i < p.Length; i++)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(o, p[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The reason for your issue is that the `Object` parameter is boxed if a value type like an enum(struct) is passed. This will cause `==` to return `false` because it's not the same reference. Use `Equals` as shown above to fix this issue and use generics to make it more efficient.

As noted you can also shorten the body of the method with LINQ:

```
return p.Contains(o, comparer);
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you :) I guess I should've went with generics from the start, my bad..

Comment: @UnknownUser you can also write `return p.Contains(o)`

Comment: This code is similar to [Enumerable.Contains](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L1370)

Comment: Interesting - .NET Core's [Contains](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Contains.cs) explicitly uses the default comparer directly to improve performance! That's worth benchmarking if the results aren't mentioned in any of the .NET Core-related perf articles

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a for loop you can use the Contains method :

```
public static bool IsEqualsTo(object o, params object[] p)
{
    return p.Contains(o);
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter True, I edit to catch this problem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter `p.Contains(o)` can handle nulls